# Get conditional branch slot from MIPS cross compiler

Tags: architecture, mips, cross-compiling, pipeline, branch-prediction

How can I get conditional branch slot, in which an instruction from before or after the branch is moved to fill in the slot, using mipsel-openwrt-linux-gcc cross compiler?

I just use the command to get the MIPS code:

```
./mipsel-openwrt-linux-gcc -O2 -fno-delayed-branch -S ha.c;
```

However, I just get nop instructions after bne instructions. The -O2 and -fno-delayed-branch options seem not working.

Here is the content of ha.c:

```
int intcompare(int *x, int *y)
{
    if (*x < *y)
        return -1;
    else if (*x > *y)
        return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int mod1(int x, int N)
{
    if (x >= N)
        x -= N;
    return x;
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

and here is the content of ha.s

```
    .file   1 "ha.c"
    .section .mdebug.abi32
    .previous
    .gnu_attribute 4, 3
    .abicalls
    .option pic0
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  intcompare
    .set    nomips16
    .ent    intcompare
    .type   intcompare, @function
intcompare:
    .frame  $sp,0,$31       # vars= 0, regs= 0/0, args= 0, gp= 0
    .mask   0x00000000,0
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    .set    noreorder
    .set    nomacro
    lw  $2,0($4)
    lw  $3,0($5)
    nop
    slt $4,$2,$3
    bne $4,$0,$L3
    nop

    slt $2,$3,$2
    j   $31
    nop

$L3:
    li  $2,-1           # 0xffffffffffffffff
    j   $31
    nop

    .set    macro
    .set    reorder
    .end    intcompare
    .size   intcompare, .-intcompare
    .align  2
    .globl  mod1
    .set    nomips16
    .ent    mod1
    .type   mod1, @function
mod1:
    .frame  $sp,0,$31       # vars= 0, regs= 0/0, args= 0, gp= 0
    .mask   0x00000000,0
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    .set    noreorder
    .set    nomacro
    slt $3,$4,$5
    move    $2,$4
    bne $3,$0,$L6
    nop

    subu    $2,$4,$5
$L6:
    j   $31
    nop

    .set    macro
    .set    reorder
    .end    mod1
    .size   mod1, .-mod1
    .section    .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .set    nomips16
    .ent    main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    .frame  $sp,0,$31       # vars= 0, regs= 0/0, args= 0, gp= 0
    .mask   0x00000000,0
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    .set    noreorder
    .set    nomacro
    move    $2,$0
    j   $31
    nop

    .set    macro
    .set    reorder
    .end    main
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (OpenWrt/Linaro GCC 4.8-2014.04 r44162) 4.8.3"
```

Comment: It looks like everything has been optimized away. There are no bne instructions.

Comment: @RichardPennington, I just modify the C code and the MIPS code in the problem. There truly are ben instructions and nop instruction next to them. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the compiler output, none of the preceding instructions can be moved into the branch delay slots, so the compiler has no choice but to fill the delay slots with `nop` instructions.

Here is an example that will use a branch delay slot (when compiled with -O or higher):

```
int add_one(int i) {
  return i+1;
}
```

mipsel-linux-uclibc-objdump output:

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <add_one>:
   0:   03e00008        jr      ra
   4:   24820001        addiu   v0,a0,1
        ...
```

What gcc optimization options were you using?

Comment: I finally used -O2 options to solve the problem. Anyway, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

With the flag `-fno-delayed-branch` you are disabling the delay slot optimization. Just use `-fdelayed-branch` to enable it.

You can add to gcc the flags -Q --help=optimizers in order to get info about which optimizations are being enabled with a certain combination of parameters.

EDIT: The output of -Q --help=optimizers might show the options you wanted the gcc to enable. However gcc can be working with a different config / flags.